# Publishing Hystrix Metrics to New Relic

Tags: java, dropwizard, newrelic, hystrix

As per documentation, New Relic has built-in support for instrumenting Hystrix. I want to  use these metrics generated by [hystrix-metrics](https://%20https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring) such as latencies and error rates, send these to **New Relic** and use them to monitor ext services for my app (very similar the [hystrix-dashboard](https://github.com/Netflix-Skunkworks/hystrix-dashboard)), but I could not find any relevant documentation apart from [this](https://newrelic.com/instant-observability/hystrix)

I am using the **dropwizard** framework for my app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like NR archived their Hystrix code as Netflix stopped developing it several years ago.
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/instrumentation/extension-additional-instrumentation-modules/#hystrix-130

You can install the archived java addon module, but its not supported officially so it may or may not give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).